# Disable resize gripper in windows?

Tags: gtk

Is it possible to disable the the new resize gripper that shows up in Ubuntu Natty/11.04?

[image]

Comment: just curious why do want to disable it?

Comment: Maybe because he uses something else (e.g. a keyboard shortcut) for resizing and this handle just needlessly takes up space?

Comment: Maybe because it draws over the top of the window contents in many applications and generally just looks annoying?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is possible to resize grippers or hide them by setting width and height to a zero. Put the following into `~/.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "default-style"
{
  GtkWindow::resize-grip-height = 0
  GtkWindow::resize-grip-width = 0
}

class "GtkWidget" style "default-style"
```

or add this strings in "default" style body of /usr/share/themes//gtk-2.0/gtkrc:

```
  GtkWindow::resize-grip-height = 0
  GtkWindow::resize-grip-width = 0
```

Comment: This is superb.

Comment: @user15328 Is this also possible for gnome3-based ubuntu(11.10,12.04)?

Answer (score 13):

You can make the grippers off by default by recompiling gtk+2 and gtk+3:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libgtk2.0-0 libgtk3.0-0
sudo apt-get install quilt
apt-get source libgtk2.0-0 libgtk3.0-0
export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches
cd gtk+2*
quilt new 999_remove_grips.patch
quilt edit gtk/gtkwindow.c
```

Find the line of code:

```
priv->has_resize_grip = TRUE;
```

Change TRUE to FALSE

```
quilt refresh
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage
cd ../gtk+3*
quilt new 999_remove_grips.patch
quilt edit gtk/gtkwindow.c
```

Find the line of code:

```
priv->has_resize_grip = TRUE;
```

Change TRUE to FALSE

```
quilt refresh
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage
```

Install the resulting deb packages and reboot.

(Of course, you'll have to do this every time there is an update for gtk)

Comment: I'm really glad @user15328 found a better solution that didn't require recompiling! Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 12):

As a user, this isn't possible. Since it would require you to manually modify the source of an application and include the below line:

```
gtk_window_set_has_resize_grip(window, false);
```

This feature was backported from GTK3 and hence the developer docs for it are on [this page.](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-has-resize-grip)

As long as you are having no problems with the grips, it's best to leave them there as they serve a very important purpose: making it easier to resize windows.

Comment: While true, it is already easy to resize with the added shadows in Ubuntu 11.04. I instinctively reach for the nearest side or corner, rather than go to the bottom right hand corner. On another note, it appears that every application now has this gripper, so I don't think that line of code was added to every application, but some sort of setting forced a resize gripper.

Comment: As far as I understand, it's a backported GTK 3 default that can be changed by adding this line. You wouldn't have to change the code to **add** this gripper.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible by editing the gtkrc theme files as I found a post on [Deviantart](http://comments.deviantart.com/1/159288029/1799232097) that mentions using pixmap engine and a transparent png.

I tried a quick edit but couldn't get it to work however someone with more knowledge of themes might be more successful.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the easiest way:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/disable-the-resize-grip-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: While this may be a perfectly good way to remove the resize gripper, -1 for providing only a link.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers