# How to remove the resize grip in gtk3 windows?

Tags: 11.10, gtk, resize

This question has already been asked and answered for GTK-2.0 here ( [Disable resize gripper in windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29209/disable-resize-gripper-in-windows) ) but I couldn't find a way to achieve this on GTK-3.0 (on Oneiric Ocelot).

I've seen the answer on the above link where it is needed to recompile GTK ... I seriously hope that's not the case with GTK-3.0 and that there's a workaround like with gtk-2.0.

Now, before someone comes and asks why I would want to remove this resize grip , here's why :

- I haven't used a resize grip or border in years, I use Alt+Click. I literally freak out when I have to use OS X or Windows.
- Sometime it shows up when it shouldn't. Splash screen, widgets, etc ...
- I don't find it visually appealing.

If this is hardcoded into gtk-3.0 then there should be an option in gconf or dconf to disable it.

I've fetched the source for gtk-3.0 and this seems to be related to the 063_resize_grip_default.patch where a configuration key is mentioned : "resize-grip-default".

When I grep for this in the themes I get this :

```
/usr/share/themes $ grep -ri resize-grip-default *
Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-default: false;
Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-default: false;
```

If this configuration value is set to false, where does the resize grip come from ?

Comment: Editing the question title. As Roland Taylor has noticed, the gtk+2.0 method still works, the question is only about gtk+3.0 then.

Comment: I just can't remember what I used to disable it in GTK+ 3.x :S

Comment: Just a quick followup: The configuration tweak at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` doesn't seem to have any effect in Ubuntu 12.10. I still get resize grips for all my gnome-terminal windows, even with the extra css rules for all widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could disable the resize grips by putting into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` the following code:

```
* {
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-default: false;
}
```

or similarly to .gtkrc-2.0

```
* {
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-height: 0;
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-width: 0;
}
```